# PL/SQL Developer parsing

Tags: parsing, plsqldeveloper, substr

I wanted to write a code to allow user to parse data, I know that the '&___' pops up an input box for user input. So what I was thinking was to allow users to enter the number of components, and then based on that another input box to allow users to enter the lengths of the substrs. for example

```
ABCD123LMNOP 
number of component =3
substr1 =1,4
substr2=5,3
subtr3=8,5
and result would be 4 columns, one with the original string, and then the three columns with the 3 substrs.
```

table name= RAW_DATA
column name= Data_VALUE

I thought about using a loop based on the user input but I wasn't sure how to get the loop working, and also that using '&___' asks for all user input at once, please let me know if this is possible on PL/SQL Developer.

Thanks in advance.